# String[] cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion?

Tags: java, types, compiler-errors

### What this code is trying to do

Desired result:

Solove the following word problem, using code:

> Also, you can use the modulus operator to extract the rightmost digit or digits from a number. For example, x % 10 yields the rightmost digit of x (in base 10). Similarly x % 100 yields the last two digits.

- Think Java, Allan Downey, Green Tea Press

### Questions

- How is this error repaired?
- Can my code be simplified or consolidated (see comments)?

### Error message

```
extRight.java:11: error: method extRight in class 
extRight cannot be applied to given types;
                int s = extRight(args);
                        ^
  required: int
  found: String[]
  reason: actual argument String[] cannot be 
  converted to int by method invocation conversion
1 error
```

### My code

```
class extRight {

    public static void extRight(int x) {
    
        x = x % 10; //initially tried `x % 10;`
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
            //initially the below was: extRight(args);
            //then: System.out.print(extRight(args));
        int s = extRight(args);
        String o = Integer.toString(s);
        System.out.print(o);
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `args` is an array of strings. How do you want to apply the remainder operation to an array of strings?

Comment: @R.J I'm on the basics (chapter 4).  Passing and returning types comes much later.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - I'm of the idea that parameter passing and return types of method would be included with the method calling tutorial. May be the tutorial you're referring to is a bit different. Happy learning nonetheless.

Comment: @RJ, I would love to hear more about your curriculum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Existing function

First of all, change the name of your function, `extRight`, to something else! It's the name of the function's class,which would be used for defining constructors of that class.

### How to assign a new value to an argument

`x` is an argument, and you cannot modify arguments like  `x = x % 10;`. Either declare a static variable, `int x`, and directly access it; or, return int from your function! Otherwise, your function will not be useful. **Ex.:**

```
//return x
public static int extRight1(int x) {

    x = x % 10;
    return x;

}
```

### Passing wrong type

You are passing `args` to `extRight`, which expects an int-type parameter: `int s = extRight(args);`.

### Automatic string conversation

You don't have to take this step: `String o = Integer.toString(s);`. You can directly write `System.out.print(s);`, as it will automatically convert the int in sysout to String before printing it to console.

### Working code

Working code would look something like what follows (with my understanding of what you want to achieve):

```
class extRight {

public static int extRight1(int x) {

    x = x % 10; 
     return x;

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    //do not forget  to pass command line args to program like this "java extRight 1"   
    int s = extRight1(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));// change indices to assign different arg[] values
   //  String o = Integer.toString(s)  you dont have to do this you can directly write
    System.out.print(s);

}

}
```

Comment: Cool name. I loved The Lion King.  Very useful explanation.

Comment: Thanks... Please mark as answer if it proved useful.

Comment: Mustafa, haven't been to a compiler, yet. I'll check all of the answers, thoroughly, tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
extRight(args) // extRight() expects an int, you are passing a String[]
```

check

```
public static void extRight(int x) { // expecting int. Also int s = extRight(args); --> this method returns nothing i.e, void

    x = x % 10; //initially tried `x % 10;`

}
```

Comment: I didn't know `String[]` was a type.  That's very useful information.

Comment: So, if I intend to use runtime arguments, I need to set the parameter to a String and convert it to an int within the method that seats `main()` parameters?  What I'm basically saying is: what should I be doing?  This is my first time doing this type of exercise (passing an `int`-type in at runtime).

Comment: Yes.. Do. Integer.parseInt(args[i])

Comment: Still totally lost.  I can imagine at least three different things this might mean.  I'm thinking about it, you know?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - No. This mean only one thing. Mismatch in type of arguments expected and sent. Period.

Comment: The error message says that.  What that means in terms of what should be done: before our conversation, I could think of a hundred things; after our conversation, I could still think of at least three.

Comment: int s = extRight(Integer.parseInt(args[i]); where "i" is your argument placeholder

Comment: Why not put it in the answer with working code, I wonder?  Because there are multiple methods, then, I don't know what method it goes into, or where it should appear in the method.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance there are two things wrong here (possibly quite a few more).  Look at your definition for the `extRight` method:

```
public static void extRight(int x)
```

Specifically the types.  The *argument* is an `int` and the `return` is `void`.  Now see how you use it:

```
int s = extRight(args);
```

`args` is a `String[]` (hence the compiler error), and what do you expect `s` to become if there's no return type?

It's not clear at all what this code is even trying to do, but to "correct the error" you would need to align your types correctly.  Simply changing the argument to a `String[]` wouldn't really work, because the method's logic needs an `int`.  Maybe you need to convert the first `args` value to an `int` and pass that to the method?  Then you'll also want to *return* something from that method it seems...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see or have wirten

```
String[] args
```

`args` is an array of `String`-Objects

Your method

```
void extRight(int x)
```

however takes an `int` as argument. The primitive type `int` and the Object type `String` are not compatible. Plus an array of objects is not compatible with a single object of the same type. You need to Iterate over the array of your arguments and do an explicit conversion/parsing of the `String` value to an `int` value.

The statement

```
x = x % 10;
```

has not the effect that you expect, in java parameters are passed by value (references too), so when you modify x inside the method, the modified value is visible only in that method. (It's not like in C where you can pass a pointer to an int!)

finally your method `extRight` has the the return type `void` which will give you error on the line

```
int s = extRight(args);
```

Your method needs to be

```
int extRight(int x)
```

Here is a modified version of your class

```
class ExtRight {
    public static int extRight(int x) {
        return x % 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(String s : args) {
            int i = extRight(Integer.parseInt(s));
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you should not name a method with the same name of The class, and that classnames should always start with an Upper case letter.

Comment: "an Array-Type is not compatible with an Object-Type": an array is a perfect `Object`.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I meant to say an array of objects is not compatible with a single object of the same type, by Object I did not mean the `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 0):

args are string-type. You need to convert arg to Int type.

Here is modified code:

```
class extRight {

public static int extRight(int x) {

    x = x % 10; //initially tried `x % 10;`
    return x;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) //convert to int
    int s = extRight(i);
    String o = Integer.toString(s);
    System.out.print(o);
}
}
```

Comment: my mistake I modified

Comment: I think it's possible that args are not string-type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your 'args' String tab into an integer :

```
int t = 0;
try {
    t = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // error : the first argument is not an integer
    t = 0;
}
s = extRight(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some very basic problems with your code.

The first problem is that you have a `String[]` and try to treat it as an `int`. A `String[]` may contain multiple values (even 0 values!), so it's not clear which one you want to treat as a number. I'll just assume you want the very first one.

The second problem is the problem of return types and call-by-value in your `extRight` function. Assigning a value to `x` inside the function will overwrite only the local variable `x`. It doesn't change the variable of the calling function (your `main`).

Here's my guess on what you want to achieve and my proposed solution:

```
class extRight {
    //this function now returns a value so that the changes by your calculations
    // can be used by the main function
    public static int extRight(int x) {
        return x % 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //this converts the first argument to an int:
        int arg = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        //the return value of your extRight function is store to the variable s
        int s = extRight(arg);
        //instead of your code, you can simply print the int variable
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```